# Error validación form request laravel 5

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

tengo un form request apuntando a un controlador en especial. El problema que tengo es que al momento de probar la validación required de los campos, me sale un error, entonces no se si estoy haciendo algo mal o puedo hacer lo que estoy haciendo de otra manera.
Por favor si pueden guiarme sería de gran ayuda.

Código del controlador:

```
public function store(VentaRequest $request) 
{
     //Obtener el Codigo de documento       
        $doc = $request->mdccod_id;

        //Rescatar codigo de impuesto
        $mim = M_DCVT::Docu($doc);
        $mim = $mim->mimpcd_id;         

        //Rescatar clave de contabilización de documento
        $clave = M_DCVT::Docu($doc);
        $clave = $clave->mdccvc;

            //Rescatar sociedad
        $soci = $request->msocod_id;
            //Rescatar codigo de impuesto (C1)
        $codim = M_IMPT::Codigo($doc);
        $codim = $codim->mimpcd;

            //Rescatar cuenta contable de impuesto
        $ccim = M_IMPT::Iva($soci, $codim);
        $ccim = $ccim->mpccct;

        //Rescatar clave de contabilizacion de impuesto
        $cvc = M_IMPT::Iva($soci, $codim);
        $cvc = $cvc->mimcvc;

        // id del cliente
        $ccli = $request->mclcod_id;
            //Obtener el codigo del cliente
        $mclie = M_CLIE::CodigoCli($ccli);
        $mclie = $mclie->mclcod;

            //Buscar la clave de contabilizacion del cliente
            $clien = M_CLIE::Clave($soci, $mclie);      
            $clien = $clien->mclvcc;

            $clien2 = M_CLIE::Clave($soci, $mclie);
            $clien2 = $clien2->mpccct;

            $mone = M_SOCI::Moneda($soci);
            $mone = $mone->moncod_id;


            //Obtener fecha y guardsarlas en la base de datos
            $fecha = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->vtfedc)->Format('Y-m-d');
            $fechac = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->vtnfecn)->Format('Y-m-d');

            //tipo cliente para cuenta de ingresos
            $tpcl = M_CLIE::TipoCli($soci, $mclie);

            //Rescatar el arreglo de ids de los materiales
            $material = $request->input('mmscod_id',[]);



            //Rescatar codigo grupo imputacion material
            $impmate = M_MTSV::Imputacion($material, $soci);

            //Variable para rescatar cuenta ingreso de la tabla dt_ctin
            $dcingre = [];
            //Rescate de la cuenta de ingreso
            $dcingre = DT_CTIN::CodImpMat($material,$soci,$tpcl,$impmate);
            //dd($dcingre);


            //Capturar cantidad de cada producto en un arreglo      
            $cant = $request->input('vtcanp',[]);
            //Capturar precio de cada producto en un arreglo
            $prec = $request->input('vtprep',[]);




            $pedido = PV_VTA::create([          
                'msocod_id' => $request->msocod_id,
                'tvtcod_id' => $request->tvtcod_id,
                'stpvcd_id' => 1
                ]);




            $documento = VT_DOC::create([
                    'msocod_id' =>$request->msocod_id,
                    'vtndoc' =>$request->vtndoc,
                    'mclcod_id' =>$request->mclcod_id,
                    'msucod_id' =>$request->msucod_id,
                    'tvtcod_id' =>$request->tvtcod_id,
                    'mdccod_id' =>$request->mdccod_id,  
                    'moncod_id' =>$mone,
                    'pvnped'=>$pedido->pvnped,                          
                    'vtfedc' =>$fecha,
                    'vtnfecn' =>$fechac,                
                    'concod_id' =>$request->concod_id,
                    'vtpjds' =>$request->vtpjds,                            
                    'mimpcd_id' => $mim,
                    'mdccvc' =>$clave,
                    'vtccim' =>$ccim,
                    'mimcvc' =>$cvc,
                    'mclvcc' =>$clien,
                    'vtpcon' =>$request->mes,
                    'vtacon' =>$request->anno,
                    'vtcccli'=>$clien2

                ]);






            $attach = [];


            foreach ($material as $k=>$id){
                $attach[$id] = [];



                // Agregar el arreglo quantity en la variable attach segun su relacion con el id del producto
                if(array_key_exists($k, $cant)){
                    $attach[$id]['vtcanp'] = $cant[$k];

                }

                // Agregar el arreglo price en la variable attach segun su relacion con el id del producto
                if(array_key_exists($k, $prec)){
                    $attach[$id]['vtprep'] = $prec[$k];


                }

                //Campo de numero rescatado de la base de datos desde otra funcion. El numero es un campo asociado al producto, el cual 
                // se ingresa automaticamente y es asociado a un solo producto en particular
                if(array_key_exists($k, $dcingre)){
                   $attach[$id]['vtccin'] = $dcingre[$k];

                }
            //Ids de los productos
                if(empty($attach[$id])){
                    $attach[$id] = $id;
                }
            }


              $documento->m_mtsv()->attach($attach);
            Session::flash('message', 'Documento creado correctamente');
           return Redirect::to('/venta');
          }
```

Request:

```
<?php namespace SIA\Http\Requests;

use SIA\Http\Requests\Request;

class VentaRequest extends Request {

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'msocod_id' => 'required',
        'mclcod_id' => 'required',
    ];




}
}
```

[image: Error]
[image]

[image]

Código de la vista:

```
<h2> Documento venta Prueba</h2> <br/>

 <div class="panel panel-default">


<div id="mensaje" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display:none"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>


            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sociedad" class="control-label">Sociedad</label>

                        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden">
                        <input type="hidden" name="mes" id="mes">
                        <input type="hidden" name="anno" id="anno"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">                          
                        <div class="form-group">

                                {!!Form::select('msocod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una sociedad -'] +$soci,null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'msocod_id', 'name'=>'msocod_id'])!!}   

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">                                    

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fecha" class="control-label">Nº Documento</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">                                
                            {!!Form::text('vtndoc', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'ingrese num'])!!}    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="socio" class="control-label">Cliente</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                {!!Form::select('mclcod_id',['' => '- Seleccione un cliente -'] +$cli,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!} 
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="colonia" class="control-label">Sucursal</label>&nbsp;

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group" id="sucu">
                            {!!Form::select('msucod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una sucursal -'] +$sucu,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}  
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Tipo venta</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                {!!Form::select('tvtcod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una sucursal -'] +$tventa,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}    
                        </div>
                    </div>                                          
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Clase Docto</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                {!!Form::select('mdccod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una clase -'] +$doc,null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=> 'mdccod_id', 'name'=>'mdccod_id'])!!} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">



                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">


                        </div>
                    </div>                                          
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Fecha Docto</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" width="20%">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <!--{!!Form::date('vtfedc', null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}  -->
                                {!!Form::text('vtfedc', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'vtfedc','name'=>'vtfedc' ,'placeholder'=>'dd-mm-aaaa','data-error'=> 'Please enter name field.'])!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Fecha Docto</label>                 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <!--{!!Form::date('vtnfecn', null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}-->  
                                {!!Form::text('vtnfecn', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'vtnfecn','name'=>'vtnfecn', 'placeholder'=>'dd-mm-aaaa'])!!}                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                -->
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">


                        </div>
                    </div>                                          
                </div>              
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tipo" class="control-label">Condición pago</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                {!!Form::select('concod_id',['' => '- Seleccione una condicion -'] +$condi,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}    
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">                                    

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fecha" class="control-label">% Descuento</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">                                
                            {!!Form::text('vtpjds', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'ingrese num', 'id' => 'vtpjds', 'name' => 'vtpjds'])!!}  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="columna">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed responsive" id="tabla">
                            <thead>
                                <tr><th></th>                                   
                                    <th>Codigo Art./servicios</th>
                                    <th>Descricpión Art./servicios</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                                    <th>Precio</th>
                                    <th>Valor neto</th>                                     
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbo">
                                <tr id="tr_1">
                                    <td width="4%" class="text-center"><a id="eliminarLinea"  ><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
                                    </td>                           
                                    <td width="23%">
                                        {!!Form::select('mmscod_id[]',['' => '- Seleccione un material -'] +$mat,null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'mmscod_id'])!!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="20%">
                                        {!!Form::text('descripcion',null, ['class' =>'form-control','id'=>'descripcion' ,'disabled'=>'disabled'])!!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="17%">
                                        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="cantidad"> -->
                                        {!!Form::text('vtcanp[]', null , ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'cantidad']) !!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="17%">
                                        {!!Form::text('vtprep[]', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'precio'])!!}

                                    </td>
                                    <td width="22%">
                                        {!!Form::text('condes', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'valorn', 'name'=>'valorn', 'disabled'=>'disabled'])!!}                                            
                                    </td>                       
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>                                
                        </table>

                        <a  class="btn btn-primary" id="addRow"><i class="entypo-plus"></i>Agregar linea</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="tabla">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>Total neto</th>
                                    <th>Valor descuento</th>
                                    <th>Monto neto</th>
                                    <th>IVA</th>
                                    <th>Monto total</th>                                        
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr id="tr1">

                                    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control total" id="total" name="total"></td>
                                    <td width="25%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vadesc" name="vadesc" onkeyup="articulo(this);" ></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="neto" name="neto" ></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="iva" name="iva" value="" ></td>
                                    <td width="20%"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="montotal" name="montotal" onkeyup="importe(this);" ></td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block btn-icon">Generar / Guardar<i class="entypo-check"></i></button>

                                                </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            <br />

        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Adjunta por favor el código de venta.blade.php

Comment: Listo, en la publicación añadí el código de la vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está relacionado con el generador de html y formularios de Laravel Collective, estás pasando en un campo de texto un array, pero la validación está esperando un string:

```
{!!Form::text('vtcanp[]', null , ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'cantidad']) !!}

{!!Form::text('vtprep[]', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'precio'])!!}
```

Al parecer al momento de recargar los valores antiguos del formulario (creo que están vacios), el generador de HTML/Forms encuentra un array vacío como valor de estos dos campos y estos no son argumentos válidos de entrada de htmlentities().

Puede que ocurra porque los campos están vacios, o que sea un bug de esa versión, el generador de formularios generalmente funciona de esa manera, así que casi que es un *feature* y no un *bug*.

---

Una posible solución para este tipo de casos es no pasar esos campos por el generador de formularios, y usar html puro:

```
<input type="text" name="vtcanp[]" class="form-control" id="cantidad">

<input type="text" name="vtprep[]" class="form-control" id="precio">
```

Comment: Gracias Shaz voy a probar y comento como me fue.

Comment: Cambie esas lineas por los inputs, pero me arroja el mismo error :/

Comment: No pueden ser exactamente los mismos errores, no estás pasando por el formbuilder.

Comment: Perdón, al final sí resulto. Reinicie el servidor de desarrollo de laravel y funcionó ahora no se cae, de verdad muchas gracias por tu ayuda.